# Attempt to install an assembly without a strong name

Tags: c#, .net, gac

I added post-build command line in my project:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe" /if "$(TargetFileName)"
```

But I got error:

```
The command exited with the code 1.
```

In output:

```
Failure adding assembly to the cache: Attempt to install an assembly without а strong name
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Assemblies in the GAC must have a strong name.

Comment: Either sign it or do not install in in the GAC

Comment: How can I remove old assembly from GAC or sign it?

Comment: Duplicate [?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493306/cannot-install-assembly-to-cache?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa?)

Comment: Yes, I have old assembly in GAC with the same name. How can I delete it?

Comment: The GAC can contain multiple versions of the same assembly.

Comment: [How to sign an assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-sign-an-assembly-with-a-strong-name)

Comment: Thank you! I deleted old assembly (gacutil –u ...), but I have the same error

Comment: Did you try signing the assembly? If you didn't you're going to consistently get this error.

Comment: yes, it works. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

There are really only two options here, don't place the assembly in the GAC or sign the assembly before putting it into the GAC.

---

The assembly needs to be signed in order to be stored in the GAC.

"Assemblies deployed in the Global Assembly Cache must have a strong name." [MSDN - Global Assembly Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac)

If you need help signing an assembly with a strong name follow this article. [MSDN - How to sign an assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-sign-an-assembly-with-a-strong-name)

---

Here are some related links:

[Cannot install assembly to cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493306/cannot-install-assembly-to-cache) <-- The current post is really a duplicate of this.

[Signing assemblies - basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939677/signing-assemblies-basics)

[C#: why sign an assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975723/c-why-sign-an-assembly?rq=1)

[How to register a non-strong-name assembly to be loaded as if it were in the GAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290006/how-to-register-a-non-strong-name-assembly-to-be-loaded-as-if-it-were-in-the-gac)